# Load an image from the database without using handler in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

The following is the Asp.Net code

```xml
<asp:TableRow ID="imagerow" runat="server">
    <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:Image ID="productimage" runat="server" ImageUrl= '<%#"data:Image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("ProductImage")) %>'  Height="30px" Width="40px" />
    </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
```

The following is the C# code

```c#
try
{
    using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        using (SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  * FROM Products", connect))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(scmd))
            {
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    connect.Open();
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    gridviewproducts.DataSource = ds;
                    gridviewproducts.DataBind();
                    connect.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

I am using the grid view control to load the image from the database.
I am using an Item Template inside a grid view control.  Using the developer tool, when I check the source of the image i get the following link `src="data:Image/png;base64,flxJbWFnZVxrYWphbC5qcGc="` when binding it to the image control. The datatype of the image is image in the database.
I do not want to use any handler for the same.

How do I bind the image to the image control?

Comment: Tested your code. It works fine. Maybe the images are not stored correctly in the db

Comment: was the image visible on the browser???

Comment: Yes it was visible